# Storing a large numpy matrix of floats in django session

Tags: python, django, numpy

I am creating a Django website to run a user study, where each user is asked a series of questions. For each user, I need to create a numpy matrix of size 45MB, where each element is a float. Whilst the matrix is initially the same for all users, it must be unique for each user as it changes according to each user's set of answers.

So, I thought that the best way to do this was to store the matrix as a session variable. In view, I would load the matrix, update it according to the user's latest answer in the study, and then save it again in session.

However, when I run the website, I get the following TypeError:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  2.80888698,  3.31793574, ...,  3.52643763,
     2.97255418,  2.5599678 ],
   [ 2.80888698,  0.        ,  2.97582224, ...,  3.23816576,
     2.64512076,  2.5242171 ],
   [ 3.31793574,  2.97582224,  0.        , ...,  4.00121959,
     3.09588744,  3.42224874],
   ..., 
   [ 3.52643763,  3.23816576,  4.00121959, ...,  0.        ,
     3.42352051,  3.29315157],
   [ 2.97255418,  2.64512076,  3.09588744, ...,  3.42352051,
     0.        ,  2.50614084],
   [ 2.5599678 ,  2.5242171 ,  3.42224874, ...,  3.29315157,
     2.50614084,  0.        ]]) is not JSON serializable
```

So, it seems that I cannot store this numpy matrix in session.

What's the solution? Should I be storing the matrix elsewhere? Or should I be converting it to a different format before storing it in session?

Comment: i don't get your mean ? do you want want to store your matrix in database ?

Comment: I don't really mind where I store it, in fact that is partly my question: If I have a large matrix for each user that changes each time the user answers a question, where should this be stored? Session? Database? Somewhere else?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have a similar situation.